# Retrieving drawable resource to send in MMS

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying start an intent to send an mms with an image I have selected from resources. This code seems to work fine if I attempt to retrieve an image from the phone's storage, but if I try to retrieve an image from the drawable resources it has trouble finding the file. I'm assumming this has to do with the fact that the Uri is not being created correctly for the purpose of retrieving the resource.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void sendImage(View v)
    {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "send image button clicked");

        Intent mmsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        mmsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.android.imagesms/drawable/smile.jpg"));
        mmsIntent.setType("image/jpg");
        startActivity(mmsIntent);
    }
}
```

If I replace

```
mmsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.android.imagesms/drawable/smile.jpg"));
```

with the code specifying a location on the phone's storage:

```
mmsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/smile.jpg")));
```

the file is retrieved correctly and the intent is started without problems.

Comment: Also, If there is a better place I should be storing these images other than resources, I would appreciated it someone would let me know. I trying to make an app with a bunch of selectable image files that you can send through text as custom emoji's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, no other app can access or read asset files or drawable files from your app. The scope of such files are limited to your app only. So you have to manually write desired file from your drawable folder to the device public storage and then fire the intent. Doing so you are making the file available to all other application (in your case message app).

---

### Saving image to sdcard from drawble resource:

Say you have an image namely ic_launcher in your drawable. Then get a bitmap object from this image like:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

The path to SD Card can be retrieved using:

```
String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
```

Then save to sdcard on button click using:

```
File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "ic_launcher.PNG");
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
```

Don't forget to add `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: Alright, so I tried what you sent to me and it seems to work well, other than the fact that it freezes up the ui, but I'll look up how to write to storage asynchronously and that should fix it. Do you know a better place that I should be storing these image files when the app is installed, or do people typically just write image resources to the sd card when they need to be used by other apps?

Comment: To expose app's local files to other apps you have to place them somewhere in public storage. So i believe this is the only preferred way.